# How to write a failing test for the thread-affinity of ObservableCollections

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, observablecollection

I have a thread safe observable collection replacement which I would like to write a unit test for. To avoid a false positive I'm trying to write a multi-threaded test that proves an object cannot be added to an ObservableCollection<> without failing so I can swap it with mine and watch it go green. I just cannot get this test to fail (using NUnit).

In no particular order I've so far tried:

- Creating the collection on a different thread and updating on current
- Creating the collection on the current thread and updating on an alternate
- Using different threading mechanisms

  - ThreadStart
  - Dispatcher
  - BackgroundWorker
- Using different apartment states

  - All combinations of STA and MTA on the test itself and/or one or both of the threads
- Creating a WPF Window to hold the collection and manipulating the Dispatcher frames manually to simulate a runtime environment.

The custom collection itself is working fine in real code so this is now more of an academic exercise than anything; My threading confidence has been shaken :)

Comment: Are you trying to get the standard observable to fail in a multithreaded scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to test something that is not there...

There is no reason for this test to fail, because the `ObservableCollection<T>` class itself *doesn't have thread affinity*. It's not thread-safe, but it just means the behavior will be unpredictable if you use it in a multithread scenario without proper locking; there is nothing in `ObservableCollection<T>` that will explicitly throw an exception if you do this.

However, the [CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) class *does* have thread affinity, which is why you can't add items to an `ObservableCollection<T>` from a different thread **if there is a `CollectionView` attached to it** (which happens, for instance, when you bind an `ItemsControl` to the collection). But it's the `CollectionView` that throws an exception, not the `ObservableCollection<T>`...

Take the following code:

```
var list = new ObservableCollection<string>();
// var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(list);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => list.Add("foo"));
```

It executes without throwing an exception, but if you uncomment the line that creates the `CollectionView`, it will throw a `NotSupportedException`:

> This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its
>   SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.

Comment: Ahh... That clears a few things up, thanks. I accepted this as the answer since it gives a one line way of getting the behavior I expected (however valid) as well as an an excellent explanation of what's really happening.